# Upload images from Flex Web Application to server

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, file-upload

My situation is that I have to convert an HTML form into a Flex WebApplication. A Java `Servlet` runs on the server that will use the data and interact with the database.

I have a couple Text fields and 2 images that need to be uploaded. The two images are browsed with 2 `FileReference` objects. I understand that I need to create a POST request on a `HTTPRequest` object, but how will I pass the image data as well?

Comment: Here is a great article about uploading files by Alex Cougarman. Check it out for some help.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/file_upload.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass image data to server in byte[] array.

Comment: how to do that along with the other form data?

Comment: In my project, I have a approach like this.

Each attache file will be stored into 1 AS Object (contains name, size, location, byte[])

Sample code: 

var listFileUpload: ArrayCollection;

var ro:Object =
 {
 data : data,
 listFileUpload  : listFileUpload
}

dataService1.executeUrl("ui01/manageTech", ro);

Hope this help.

Comment: how can i get the byteArray from the fileReference object, the properties that i can use are only name, size and dateModified. There is a method called upload() also...

Comment: You can try this:
var fileUpload: FileReference;

ASObject.data       = fileUpload.data;

Hope this help

Comment: Should add 2 event handler of file reference:


    fileUpload.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSelectFile);
    fileUpload.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteFile);

onSelectFile(e:Event)
{
fileReference.Load();
}
and in onCompleteFile(e:Event) {
var fileUpload: FileReference = e.currentTarget as FileReference;; 
ASObject.data = fileUpload.data; 
}

Comment: I have done all that, but `flash.net.FileReference` doesn't have a property called `data`

Comment: Which Flex version are you using now?

Flex 3.0 already has this property.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html